# Rpi 3B+ Clam Antivirus hanging

Tags: pi-3b+, security

Whenever I launch "Clam Antivirus" in my Raspberry pi 3B+ , it starts hanging when I click any button . How to scan files without hanging ?

Answer (score 1):

The ClamAV [website lists the requirements](https://docs.clamav.net/Introduction.html?highlight=requirements#recommended-system-requirements) for the current version as 3GB RAM on a 2 GHz processor.

I wouldn´t think it impossible that the version in the Raspberry repositories is built or configured to be less demanding, but I still think it is aimed primarily at the 4 or 8 GB Raspberry 4 models.

If you want to try it on a 3B+ (disclaimer: I never have), make sure you have a large enough swap file, at least 2 GB. The default in Buster is only 100MB.

You can find how to increase it [here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-swap-file/).

As for what it scans for (re the comments), besides Windows files, it also scans ELF (Linux) binaries and several cross-platform types (html, java, ...).